# Как сделать так, чтобы калькулятор диcкриминанта выводил и целые, и округленные числа?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я решил сделать калькулятор дискриминанта, но он не выводит округлённые значения. Как это можно исправить?

```
import math
a = int(input('Введите a '))
b = int(input('Введите b '))
c = int(input('Введите c '))
D = (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c)
if D > 0 and D == round(D):
    x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
    print('Корни:', "\nx1(+) = " + str(x1), '\nx2(-) = ' + str(x2))
if D > 0 and not D == round(D):
    x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
    print('Корни:', "\nx1(+) ≈ " + str(round(x1)), '\nx2(-) ≈ ' + str(round(x2)))
if D < 0:
    print('Корней нет')
if D == 0:
    x = -(b / (2 * a))
    print('x = ' + str(round(x)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

мне кажется вы зашли не с того конца :)

есть 2 случая дискриминанта (D >= 0) - полный квадрат или нет

и возможно в связи с этим 3 вида решения: целое, рациональное и иррациональное

проверить дискриминант на полный квадрат можно так:

```
int(D**.5)**2 == D
```

дальше я бы воспользовался библиотекой `Fraction` чтобы работать с дробями в случае дискриминанта как полного квадрата, что позволило бы решить вопрос сокращения дробей

и лишь для иррациональных дискриминантов использовал бы `float` и округление (а его можно уже делать как вам удобнее)